# Webkit Picture in Picture resets itself on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, mobile-safari, picture-in-picture

When using the following code on a HTML video tag:

```
video.webkitSetPresentationMode("picture-in-picture");
```

It works as expected on safari. but on IOS safari, the moment picture in picture mode is activated it closes again. The black overlay with the "This video is playing in picture in picture" text is shown, but immediately removed again. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I'm using this article as reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/adding_picture_in_picture_to_your_safari_media_controls

Comment: Running into the same issue with WebKit webViews

Comment: Anyone know a solution?